# Trying to stop a bone from rotating after setting rotation constraint

Tags: rigging, bones, bone.constraints

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to rig this arm and am trying to apply a Copy Rotation to this finger and have it constrained to the controller bone. When I do, the finger bone rotates to the same position as the controller. How can I constrain the finger bone to the controller while keeping its current rotation?

Comment: In the constraint, try to change Target and Owner from World to Local Space? Or please share your file

Comment: Hi @moonboots,
Here's the project, same character project you helped me out with yesterday: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16SpZLVubnlQdYPHyaq5MoKCNoRXdrIcM/view?usp=sharing

I tried setting target/owner to local and it solves the jumping problem, but the axes to rotate don't align now.

Comment: How is it supposed to rotate? You could simply rotate the bone in Edit mode (Ctrl R 90 to rotate it 90°). Also, it has nothing to do with it but make sure that the head of the controller bone (WristIK.Left) stick to the center of the hand so that the hand doesn't jump towards it when you switch to Pose mode

Comment: @moonboots
I want the first bone of every finger (PINKY1, POINT1, MIDDLE1, THUMB1) to have its rotation constrained to WristK.Left.

As far as making sure the controller doesn't jump, how do I stick it to the center of the hand? In the tutorial I'm following, he moves it back in Y space, similar to where I have it when the Armature is in Edit mode. What is causing it to jump to the center of the hand when I go back to Object Mode?

Comment: It's the IK constraint that makes the bone jumps to its controller, so in Edit mode just move the head of the controller to the tail of the other bones. Yes I understand that you want the fingers to rotate, to change their rotation axis, in Edit mode, select the finger bone and Ctrl R 90 to make it rotate 90° (or 180°, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to make the head of the controller stick to the tail of the IK bone so that the IK bone doesn't jump to its controller once in *Pose* mode. To make the head of the controller stick to the IK tail, put the 3D cursor at the tail position, select the head of the controller, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*:

[image]

As for the rotation axis of the fingers, select the finger bone in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>90</kbd> (or whatever angle). Also, in Pose mode, open its constraint and choose *Target/Owner > Local Space* instead of *World Space*, result:

[image]